# Connecting Azure app service to MongoDB Atlas across vnet peering connection

Tags: java, mongodb, azure, azure-web-app-service, mongodb-atlas

So I have an Azure App Service and I want it to be able to connect to mongo db atlas. For our Atlas setup there is [a peering connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/) between our managed environment on azure (and the vnet it all sits in) and our mongo db cluster.

The mongo cluster is setup with "Connect via peering only" which we can't change. This means we can't connect to our db with any old public ip address -It has to come from the vnet it's peered with. The vms (from within the peered vnet) are able to access the db no problem.

I tried with the app service to connect to the db with the same connection string that worked for the vm. It returned a the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}, {address=MYMONGOADDRESS.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]
```

This is expected due to the reasons above. However I setup the [vnet integration for the app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)
. I created a dedicated subnet as described for the app service and whitelisted the ip range in mongo. However I still couldn't connect to the db after using this vnet integration. I also got a very similar error but slightly different.

```
{java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}, {address=MYMONGOADDRESS.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out}}]
```

Where instead of a connection refused I'm not getting a connection time out. I've repeated this a few times and get the same result.

Anyone know why these errors are different and any help in being able to connect to the db from my azure app service?

Comment: can you try it from another app in the same app service plan to see if you get the same error

Answer (score 1):

No idea if this can apply to your case but this question was the first and only that came up when I was searching for something similar.

In my case I have a MongoDB Atlas deployed on Azure and an app running in AKS. I set up peering as documented but still could not connect from the app container in AKS to the MongoDB. Turns out the problem was an incorrect connection string.

Atlas has a different URL when connecting directly and when connecting through a peer network:

```
# Direct connection
mongo "mongodb+srv://<cluster>.<something>.mongodb.net/<dbname>"

# Peered connection (note the -pri)
mongo "mongodb+srv://<cluster>-pri.<something>.mongodb.net/<dbname>"
```

As an additional note, I configured the Atlas Network Acces IP address list with the CIDR of the Azure VN Subnet used in AKS. (Under `Virtual Network > Subnets > IPv4`)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any firewall or network security group? What the network peering status is? If it shows « initiated » then this means it has not been completed. Network peering has to be done on each ends. If it shows « connected », then I would look for firewall or network security groups.

See this 
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/#vpc-peering

Comment: The peering is showing as connected - Also the application hosted on a vm within the virtual network is able to connect to the db so the peering clearly works. It seems to have trouble with the web application's vnet integration. I've also double checked the network security groups and there's no firewall

Answer (score 0):

FYI Peering is not available on M0, M2, M5 and Serveless(at this time) instances.